# Generate xml from table data--oracle 12c

Tags: xml, oracle

How to generate below xml.
My requirement is self close tag for ProductionData.

Required Output--

```
<Header>
     <MeterUnit sno="1"    meterid="121">
         <ProductionData   manufacture="abc"/>
     </MeterUnit>
</Header>

Table Details:
Tablename: meterinfo.
Columnname: sno, meterid, manufacture.
Data:1 121 abc
```

My Query--

```
select xmlelement("Header",
        xmlelement("MeterUnit",xmlattributes(sno as sno, meterid as meterid),xmlelement("ProductionData",xmlattributes(manufacture as manufacture))))
             from meterinfo;
```

My Output

```
<Header>
    <MeterUnit sno="1" meterid="121">
        <ProductionData   manufacture="abc"></ProductionData>
    </MeterUnit>
</Header>
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? If it's from relational tables, show us the table structures and sample data that relates to the output you want, along with your current query and the (presumably incorrect) output it produces.

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole for your comment. I have updated the details.

Comment: After some analysis i found that i am missing something that is xmlroot function, Below is the required query:

select xmlroot(xmlelement("Header",
                    xmlelement("MeterUnit", xmlattributes(sno as sno, meterid as meterid),xmlelement("ProductionData", xmlattributes(manufacture as manufacture))))
,version '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') from meterinfo;

Answer (score 1):

Don't use XMLRoot, it was introduced as a placeholder while the XMLSerialize() function was being standardized. 
You appear to be want to add an xml declaration. That is a function of the XML serialization and should be added using XMLSerialize(), which turns the XML object into text..

Answer (score 0):

As @MarkDrake sugegsted, you can use [`XMLSerialize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions268.htm) instead of [`XMLRoot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions266.htm), for instance:

```
select xmlserialize(document xmlelement("Header",
  xmlelement("MeterUnit", xmlattributes(sno as sno, meterid as meterid),
    xmlelement("ProductionData", xmlattributes(manufacture as manufacture)))
) indent size=2)
from meterinfo;

XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLELEMENT("HEADER",XMLELEMENT("METERUNIT",XMLATTRIBUTES(SN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Header>
  <MeterUnit SNO="1" METERID="121">
    <ProductionData MANUFACTURE="abc"/>
  </MeterUnit>
</Header>
```

or

```
select xmlserialize(document xmlelement("Header",
  xmlelement("MeterUnit", xmlattributes(sno as sno, meterid as meterid),
    xmlelement("ProductionData", xmlattributes(manufacture as manufacture)))
) version '1.0')
from meterinfo;

XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENTXMLELEMENT("HEADER",XMLELEMENT("METERUNIT",XMLATTRIBUTES(SN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Header>
  <MeterUnit SNO="1" METERID="121">
    <ProductionData MANUFACTURE="abc"/>
  </MeterUnit>
</Header>
```

You might also want to read more about other ways to convert relational data to XML [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb13gen.htm).